# get nearest next one date records in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

i am having an event table.and i show events for today using.
`` SELECT *
FROM `special_banner_tbl`
WHERE `SPLBANNER_pubsdate` = current_date ``

 if there is no events for today, it have to display the future day record which is more near to current date. 
if the table like..
------------------
future_date
------------------
30-11-2013
30-11-2013
02-12-2013
03-12-2013
03-12-2013
----------------------
it will display the next nearest date **30-11-2013** records.. like.
 `` SELECT * FROM `special_banner_tbl` WHERE `SPLBANNER_pubsdate` = nest_nearest_date_records ``

only one nearest future date records without any **limit**. like
---------------     --------------
events                          future-dates
---------------   ----------------
30th-events   30-11-2013
30th-events   30-11-2013
------------------------------

Comment: guys thanks for your answers, but i need 31-11-2-13 records only which is more near than today.and i don't what its limit,and the dates 02-12-2013 and further future dates..

Comment: i need only the next events date records only without any limit.. please help..

Comment: I am really worried to know how your database column accepted the date with `31` days for `November`. ***`31-11-2013`***. My database has kicked me with `ERROR 1292 (22007)`

Comment: hey it just for an example friend...

Answer (score 2):

Anyway I would write two separate queries for this case but this also works fine:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM special_banner_tbl
WHERE SPLBANNER_pubsdate = CURRENT_DATE

UNION ALL 
SELECT 
    *
FROM special_banner_tbl
WHERE 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM special_banner_tbl 
    WHERE SPLBANNER_pubsdate=CURRENT_DATE) = 0 
    AND 
    SPLBANNER_pubsdate = (
        SELECT MIN(SPLBANNER_pubsdate) 
        FROM special_banner_tbl 
        WHERE SPLBANNER_pubsdate > CURRENT_DATE 
        ORDER BY SPLBANNER_pubsdate
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need or SPLBANNER_pubsdate > current_date for the future dates and the order by SPLBANNER_pubsdate  ASC so if no events found for current date it will have future events if found then current events are listed first

```
SELECT * FROM `special_banner_tbl` WHERE `SPLBANNER_pubsdate` = current_date
OR `SPLBANNER_pubsdate` > current_date ORDER BY `SPLBANNER_pubsdate` ASC
 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: what happens if there exists only 5 current date records and the rest are future dates

Comment: 5 events of current date will be listed first and 25 future events will also be there but after current events

Comment: OP wants to list future dates only when no current date records are available

Comment: Then he needs to do this check with php not in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you have to do is use the difference between today and the future. Then you would have to order your data by this difference ascending.

Hope I helped!

Comment: no i don't what to order any records. i need only the next future date events records..

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  `special_banner_tbl`
ORDER BY 
  ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), `SPLBANNER_pubsdate`))
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `jsproduct_company`
WHERE future_date > NOW()
LIMIT 1;
```

You can find exact next date record with above query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `special_banner_tbl`
WHERE `SPLBANNER_pubsdate` >= CURDATE()
ORDERBY `SPLBANNER_pubsdate` asc
LIMIT 1
```

If your field `SPLBANNER_pubsdate` would contain full datetime values (instead of date values), you would have to change the `where` clause a bit, to isolate the date:

```
SELECT *
FROM `special_banner_tbl`
WHERE DATE(`SPLBANNER_pubsdate`) >= CURDATE()
ORDERBY `SPLBANNER_pubsdate` asc
LIMIT 1
```